# How to store values in SignalR State Variables

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm using OnConnected and OnDisconected to keep trap of users and reduce memory.

My problem is that I can't assign any variables in SignalR. I'm using the following code.

When I read Clients.Caller.userid it's always null. However I can read it fine immediately after I assign it which xxSameProcess variable is not null.

Is there something that I'm missing?

```
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
    {
        var user = CreateUser();
        Clients.Caller.userid = user.UserId;
        object xxSameProcess = Clients.Caller.userid;

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        object xx = Clients.Caller.userid;

        CreateDelete( Clients.Caller.userid );

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

Comment: I'm quite sure the state object is not available anymore after disconnection (the event is triggered after disconnection). You can double check by trying to access your userId from inside a regular Hub's method, it should be there. I also think you could use the ConnectionId for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Looks like you can't store variables onConnected and OnDisconnected.

Answer (score 1):

On my side, I store my variable from the client when it connects

```
        <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function ($) {
                //some stuff
                $.connection.hub.qs = { 'uid': '@guid' };
                $.connection.hub.start();
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
```

The, I can access it from the server with the query strings

```
public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var uid = Context.QueryString["uid"];
        //some stuff

    return base.OnConnected();
}

public override Task OnDisconnected()
{
    var uid = Context.QueryString["uid"];
    //some stuff

    return base.OnDisconnected();
}

public override Task OnReconnected()
{
    var uid = Context.QueryString["uid"];

    //some stuff

    return base.OnReconnected();
}
```

Comment: You will probably want to combine this with UserIdProvider. Then you can remove all the calls to grab it from the query string.

Comment: In my situation, I add to do this because the UserIdProvider and the current user can be different (it was the specs)

Comment: The user id provider is whatever you want it to be. You can even have conditional logic in there.    
    public class UserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
    {
        public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
        {
            string userId = request.QueryString["vid"];
           if (userId.IsEmpty())
            {
                if (request.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                   return request.User.Identity.Name;
                }

                return null;
            }

            return userId;
        }
    }

Comment: I can have two users with one session ;)